# Ubuntu iso customization with a different kernel version, hangs on initramfs

Tags: kernel, iso, initramfs

I am trying to build a customized ubuntu iso based on ubuntu Bionic Beaver :

```
129292a182136a35e1f89c586dbac2e2  ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso
```

I followed this tutorial : `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization`
I chrooted into the extracted squashfs and installed some debian packets I wanted, downloaded a new kernel from `http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15.3/`, the launched the `mkinitramfs -o /initrd.gz 4.15.3-041503-generic` command.

Then I used the following commands to rebuild the iso:

```
sudo rm -f iso/casper/vmlinuz iso/casper/initrd.lz
sudo cp squashfs/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.3-041503-generic iso/casper/vmlinuz 
sudo cp squashfs/initrd.gz iso/casper/initrd.lz
sudo chmod a+w iso/casper/filesystem.manifest
sudo chroot squashfs dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Package} ${Version}\n' > iso/casper/filesystem.manifest
sudo chmod go-w iso/casper/filesystem.manifest
sudo rm iso/casper/filesystem.squashfs
cd squashfs
sudo mksquashfs . ../iso/casper/filesystem.squashfs -info
cd ..
cd iso
sudo bash -c "find . -path ./isolinux -prune -o -type f -not -name md5sum.txt -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | tee md5sum.txt"
cd ..
sudo mkisofs -r -V "my_custom_iso" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o custom-livecd.iso iso 
sudo isohybrid custom-livecd.iso
```

I tried to boot virtualbox on the newly created iso, it seems to work since I can see the splash screen of ubuntu loading but then it hangs on the initramfs shell :
[image: initramfs]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is the code for the message](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2347977&p=13589447#post13589447):

```
 # Confirm the final format was valid.
    if [ "${UNIONFS}" != "unionfs-fuse" ]; then
        modprobe "${MP_QUIET}" -b "${UNIONFS}" || true
        if cut -f2 /proc/filesystems | grep -q "^${UNIONFS}\$"; then
            :
        else
            panic "/cow format specified as ${UNIONFS} and no support found"
        fi
    fi
```

- 1st IF is always true.
- 2nd IF: if union-fs can not be found in /proc/filesystems error notice.
- Basically you are missing an overlay
- Seems to be a [bug](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/foundations-bugs/2016-May/282312.html) in Casper 1.34+

[Fix](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2347977&p=13590020#post13590020):

- edit `/shared/livecd/work/rootfs/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`
- add `overlay.ko`
- run `update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)`

Comment: It works, but I am stuck on another issue (some kind of black screen with dots aligned), should I open a new thread or continue this topic?

Comment: @aze new question would be preferable.