# Ubuntu iso customization with a different kernel version, boot screen is scrambled

Tags: boot, kernel, iso

Following this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045827/ubuntu-iso-customization-with-a-different-kernel-version-hangs-on-initramfs)
I am trying to build a customized ubuntu iso based on ubuntu Bionic Beaver :

```
129292a182136a35e1f89c586dbac2e2  ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso
```

I followed this tutorial : `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization`
I chrooted into the extracted squashfs and installed some debian packets I wanted, downloaded a new kernel from `http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15.3/`, the launched the `mkinitramfs -o /initrd.gz 4.15.3-041503-generic` command.

Then I used the following commands to rebuild the iso:

```
sudo rm -f iso/casper/vmlinuz iso/casper/initrd.lz
sudo cp squashfs/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.3-041503-generic iso/casper/vmlinuz 
sudo cp squashfs/initrd.gz iso/casper/initrd.lz
sudo chmod a+w iso/casper/filesystem.manifest
sudo chroot squashfs dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Package} ${Version}\n' > iso/casper/filesystem.manifest
sudo chmod go-w iso/casper/filesystem.manifest
sudo rm iso/casper/filesystem.squashfs
cd squashfs
sudo mksquashfs . ../iso/casper/filesystem.squashfs -info
cd ..
cd iso
sudo bash -c "find . -path ./isolinux -prune -o -type f -not -name md5sum.txt -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | tee md5sum.txt"
cd ..
sudo mkisofs -r -V "my_custom_iso" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o custom-livecd.iso iso 
sudo isohybrid custom-livecd.iso
```

When booting with virtualbox, I can see the loading screen of ubuntu and then the logs of ubuntu loading but then the screen is scrambled. 
First : 
[image: loading scrambled]

And after a while, the screen becomes more like this :
[image: screen scrambled]

I tried following this [solution](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1541446), changing `iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg` into :

```
if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=1280*1024
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

set timeout=5
menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x1024-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x1024-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x1024-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap oem-config/enable=true ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x1024-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
```

The screen is still scrambled but in a different way :

[image: screen scrambled 2]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with this configuration of `iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

```
if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
        set gfxmode=1280*1024
        insmod efi_gop
        insmod efi_uga
        insmod gfxterm
        terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

set timeout=5
menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
        set gfxpayload=keep
        linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper  nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x1024-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap ---
        initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
        set gfxpayload=keep
        linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity  nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x1024-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap ---
        initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
        set gfxpayload=keep
        linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity  nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x1024-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap oem-config/enable=true ---
        initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
        set gfxpayload=keep
        linux   /casper/vmlinuz  boot=casper integrity-check  nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x1024-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap ---
        initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
```